# Fire+Smoke Simulation isn´t working with motion

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

Im trying to make a scene where a helicopter flies in the camera view and shoots rockets at the camera. I want to make a fire and smoke trail behind the rockets but i cant get the simulation to work. I created a very good looking Fire + Smoke but when the domain with the flow object is mooving with the rocket it looks terrible. I tried every solution that came to my mind but nothing worked please help.
[Without Motion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Im7y.jpg)
[With Motion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYrVm.jpg)

[image: Without Motion][image: With Motion][image: Scene]

Comment: you shouldn't move the domain object....

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to make the domain as big as the rocket´s path but it ended that the simulation got way to big. After that i tried to scale the flow source but it didnt worked. I also tried to upres increase the resolution divisions but it didnt helped.

Comment: What if you turn on Adaptive Domain, which will resize to domain to track only the volume that is needed.   However this may still end up being too large of a domain.

Comment: Yeah im already using Adaptive Domain thats not the problem.